# offsetting textures of cycles materials to simulate movement

Tags: texturing, materials, transforms

I have a tank and some treads with a texture that can be translated along the x axis to simulate tread movement.
This is easily done in the blender internal render by going to the texture tab, under mapping there is a section called offset, and I can easily keyframe it to change the treads "movement".
However, considering how you apply a texture in cycles, you can not do this, it seems unless you are able to use textures created in the texture tab rather than in the nodes or material tab.

Thanks for reading and any response is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a *Vector > Mapping* node after the *Texture Coordinates* node, and plug that as vector for the texture.

To offset the texture, animate the values for *Location* (and/or *Rotation* or *Scale*)

[image]

Comment: thank you very much i was messing around with xy cords and vector but i never saw the mapping node thanks